# Need to understand concept of Buoyant force

Tags: buoyancy, weight

I want to know that is there any influence created by shape of container when apparent weight is calculated for example in following figure apparent weight in all container will same or not.[image]

Comment: read and understand pascla's law for better understanding :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Regardless of the shape of the container,* the buoyant force can be calculated experimentally by finding the *difference* in the readings of the balance to which the object is attached *between two cases:* (a) the object is out of liquid, (b) the object is submerged inside the liquid (partially or completely.) So, the answer will be, "Only the difference in the readings of the balance is relevant to determine the buoyant force experimentally; the shape of the container is irrelevant."

Answer (score 0):

write the equation by assuming the system is in equilibrium:
$$T+B=mg$$$$\implies B=mg-T$$
and in this equaiton we don't see anything which is depending on the shape of the container ($T$ is depending on the volume of the block and it is not related to volume or shape of container).

> and the relative weight calculated will be the **same**

Answer (score 0):

The upthrust (buoyancy force) due to a fluid is there because the pressure due to the fluid varies with depth.
The shape of the object containing the fluid does not change the variation of pressure with depth, so the upthrust is independent of the shape of the container.